# Kotlin: count occurrences of `charArray` in `String`

Tags: string, kotlin

I have two strings

```
val string1 = "Hello"
val string2 = "Hello world"
```

I have to count existence of each letter from `string1` in `string2` in `Kotlin`

So far, I have written this much code and stuck with regex

```
val string1_array = string1.toCharArray()
val pattern = Regex("") // Regex pattern here
val matcher = string2

val count = pattern.findAll(matcher).count()
```

What should be the appropriate Regex pattern to search for charArray? Is there some better way to do in Kotlin

Comment: You don't need any regex to count characters in a string. Just use a loop (or any other kind of iteration).

Comment: Could you add your expected logic please?

Comment: Do you need to count each char separately? E.g. how many times you have 'H', how many times 'e' and so on?

Comment: Here's a 1 line solution using Kotlin's collection functions:
    val occurrences = string2.filter{ it in string1}
                        .groupingBy { it }
                        .eachCount()

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the below higher order method,

```
val count = string2.count{ string1.contains(it) }
print(count)
```

Answer (score 21):

Here are some [`String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html) extension functions you can use

### Occurrences of any char

With the [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/fold.html) extension function:

```
val string1 = "Hello"
val string2 = "Hello world Hello"

print(
     string2.fold(0) {
         sum: Int, c: Char ->
         if (string1.contains(c))
             sum + 1
         else
             sum
     }   
)
```

Or even shorter with [`sumBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/sum-by.html):

```
string2.sumBy { 
    if (string1.contains(it))
        1
    else
        0
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
string2.count { string1.contains(it) }
```

Or shortest:

```
string2.count { it in string1 }
```

### Occurrences of each char individually

With [`forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/for-each.html) and a [`MutableMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/index.html):

```
val charsMap = mutableMapOf<Char, Int>()

string2.forEach{
    charsMap[it] = charsMap.getOrDefault(it, 0) + 1
}

print(charsMap)
```

### Occurrences of the whole `string1`

With the [`windowed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/windowed.html) extension function:

```
string2.windowed(string1.length){
    if (it.equals(string1))
        1
    else
        0
}.sum()
```

You can browse more `String` extension functions in the [`String` stblib page](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sum +1`and `sum` as returns?

Comment: @leoderprofi absolutely! Forgot them. I'll add a map variant for each char shortly too

Comment: Nice use of windowed when searching for the whole string! I slightly prefer to do that like this: `string2.windowed(string1.length).filter { it == string1 }.count()`

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer imho, thank you for introducing me to windowed, I'm new to Kotlin/FP.

Answer (score 13):

Just use Kotlin's collection functions

```
val occurrences = string2.filter{ it in string1}
                        .groupingBy { it }
                        .eachCount()
```

Answer (score 8):

Simplified use case when you only want to count occurrences of a single character:

```kotlin
println("needle in a haystack".count{ c -> c == 'a' })
// OUTPUT: 3
```

Reference:

- https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/count.html

Answer (score 2):

**To answer actual the question**: the simplest regex pattern would be to use a character class syntax `"[" + string1 + "]"`. Beware, this is not always well behaved. It works well for all ASCii letters and numbers. Special characters like `\^-?!` must be properly escaped. For the rules see https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {
    val string1 = "Hello"
    val string2 = "Hello world Hello"

    val string1_array = string1.toCharArray()
    val pattern = Regex("[" + string1 + "]") // Regex pattern here
    val matcher = string2

    val count = pattern.findAll(matcher).count()
    print(count)
}
```

**How to solve the task:** Imho the best way to do this task is to use `filter` or `count` instead of regex, because the you don't have to use any special syntax.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {
        val string1 = "Hello"
        val string2 = "Hello world Hello"
        //returns all chars of string2 contained in string1 as list
        val count = string2.filter { string1.contains(it) }.length
        //an other a bit shorter solution with count
        count = string2.count{ string1.contains(it) }
        print(count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use chars from the first string as map keys, for example:

```
val string1 = "Hello"
val string2 = "Hello world"

val chars = HashMap<Character, Int>()

for (char in string1) // fill keys
    chars[char] = 0

for (char in string2) // count occurrences
    chars[char]?.let {
        chars[char] = it + 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val x = name.count({ch->ch=='z'}) //if you want to count 'z'
```