# Kotlin efficient way to search text in xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, search

In my project I have multiples xml file that I downloaded in internal memory of my application. I would like to be able to search a word in those file.
I am able to able to get the text of my file like this :

var file = File("myPath", "filename.xml")

Then I used readfile and contain to know if the file contain my word :

```
var content = file.readText()
var contain = content.contains("wordiamlokingfor")
```

if contain is true then the word appear in my file.

My problem is that first of all it's only search for one occurrence of my word and I would like to know how many times the word appear in the file. Then if I have to open every file and to look in every one of them, this seem to be very unefficient and taking a long time.

So I would like to know if there is a way, maybe using buffer or something else, to search text in multiple xml file. That is efficient, speaking in time and memory ? And finding all occurence of the word.

**EDIT**

As someone sugested, i used :

```
content.windowed(myword.length){
                if (it.equals(string1))
                    1
                else
                    0
            }.sum()
```

And this gave me the number of occurence of my word in my file.
Now i would like to know if there is a better search option than opening all files and read all content of each one ?

Comment: Look here to see how to count the number of occurenes of a substring in string, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846295/kotlin-count-occurrences-of-chararray-in-string

Comment: I tied it, but when i do : content.count {wordiamlokingfor. contains(it)} or any other method, i find result that has nonsense, i find occurence > 1000 when the text is only 500 word. And i find 100 occurence when i look for word that doesnt existe for exemple "efjwfnefn". Maybe i'am missing something?

Comment: ok this count the occurence of the char, i was able to get the count with windowed thanks.